# Insert values using EF core generates a complicated query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've created an app that inserts about 100k records into a database. I'm using EF core, like:

```
context.Users.AddRange(users);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I expected it to generate a simple insert query, like `insert into users (...) values (...)`. But, this is the monstrosity it generated instead:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE (..., [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [dbo].[Users] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, 0),
(@p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, 1),
(@p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, 2)

...

) AS i (..., _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (...)
VALUES (...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;
```

It did not even include all the items in one request. It ran the query multiple times, inserting about 3k records at a time. Obviously, this code is really slow. I found a similar question that suggested setting `MaxBatchSize` or `UseRelationalNulls`, but none of that helped in my case. Even if I decrease `MaxBatchSize` to 1 (that would make it run 100k queries), EF still generates the same weird code. And in case I set `MaxBatchSize` to 100k, it still generates batches with about 3k items at a time. So, it looks like `MaxBatchSize` doesn't actually work in this case.

So, is there any way to make EF Core generate a faster insert code?

Comment: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - here you can find some interesting libraries. Some of them allow you to do efficient inserts. I'd recommend linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: (1) *"Obviously, this code is really slow"* Why do you think so? The code is not weird, its a way to do batch inserts and return the auto-generated values with one SQL statement. (2) Setting `MaxBatchSize` really controls the generated SQL statement, if you are getting the same when `MaxBatchSize == 1`, most likely you are doing something wrong, since it definitely works.

Comment: `MaxBatchSize` does work with 1. It doesn't allow me to insert more than about 3k records at a time, though. It must be related to the maximum amount of parameters allowed in a single query.

Comment: That's true (regarding max parameters per SQL limit). But do you really have performance issues and are you sure they are caused by that SQL statement(s) (and not the change tracker for instance). There are other libraries which can do faster inserts by using SqlBulkCopy, but none of them can effectively return the generated Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core is trying to generate insert query and return back generated ID's and other fields which are initialized by database, `_Position` in your case. An there is no way to generate **insert and forget** statements via ChangeTracker.

I would suggest to use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (Disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

```cs
await context.BulkCopyAsync(users);
```

100K records will be inserted approximately in 1 second.

Comment: I've ended up using a default SqlBulkCopy in combination with FastMember library.

Comment: Well, but It will not allow you to use massive update, Merge, CTE, etc.